# Is 'He would always say' a valid alternative for 'He always said'?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

> He would always say hello to me when he saw me in the street.

Is this sentence equal to 'He always said Hello to me when he saw me in the street'? If not how can I write it without 'would'?

Comment: Both of these are fine. Another alternative is "He always used to say . . . "

Comment: Whenever he saw me in the street he said 'Hello'.

Comment: "Would", to me, has a suggestion of past events that won't be repeated, as if he had died.  e.g. "He would... but won't any more."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, yes, but to me the simple past makes the same suggestion.

Comment: @jackO'Flaherty I haven't found any information about that usage in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/.  Where are you from? Could you provide some more information about it?

Comment: @Armen I'm in the middle of the USA. I can't point to supporting information, it's just the way I hear the expression with "would".

Comment: @JackO'flaherty thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one very small difference: "He would always..." (or similar things like "he always used to") makes a *vague or general* statement about a tendency. For instance:

> "Your honor, the defendant is a kind person. I grew up on his block, and he would always say 'Hello' to me when he saw me in the street."
> "Oh really? We have video evidence here that on June 15th he passed you and did *not* say hello!"
> "Come on, you know what I mean! It's a figure of speech! Maybe you found one time when he didn't, but I mean that he *usually* did."

If I used a construction that omitted "would"—"He always said 'hello' to me"—I might have the same meaning, but the connotation would be just a bit more absolute. I might still mean "usually," but my exact words have now claimed that it happened *every time*. If someone tried to prove me wrong, I might still claim that they're missing my point, but I might not be so exasperated at them for interpreting my words unreasonably.

Comment: Right, and would is almost used to always say.

Comment: @AndyBonner Hi. Thank you for the answer. If I got it right ('would say'- can be 90% of the truth) ('said' - can be 99%-100% of the truth) and for 100% of the truth it is something like 'said every time'? Is it right?